# Speeding up Sql query using CROSS APPLY() eliminating ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, row-number, cross-apply

**Goal:**

I want to speed up a sql query of about a million rows of transaction data (order data).  I've been able to reduce the time from 50 minutes (using temp tables) to 9 minutes using CROSS APPLY() (see query below).  Is there a way I can eliminate using ROW_NUMBER() to find the highest dollar amount spend by a customer / year (group by customer, year)?  ROW_NUMBER() can be computationally expensive.  Additionally there are no indexes on these tables.

**Code:**

```
select z.string_customer_name, z.string_customer_region, z.string_industry_group, 
  z.string_city, z.string_state, z.string_country, z.string_booking_type, 
  z.string_sales_branch, z.string_sales_region, z.string_sales_area,
  z.int_booking_year, z.float_sum_total, z.string_tpis_concat, z.string_groupby
from (
    select #temp_00.*, ca_01.float_sum_total, ca_00.string_tpis_concat, 
      ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by #temp_00.string_groupby order by #temp_00.string_groupby, 
        ca_01.float_sum_total) as row_num
    from #temp_00
    cross apply(
        select string_groupby, int_booking_year, sum(float_total) as float_sum_total
        from #temp_00
       group by string_groupby, int_booking_year
    ) as ca_01
    cross apply(
        select string_groupby, STRING_AGG(cast(string_customer_tpi 
          as varchar(max)), '|') as string_tpis_concat
        from #temp_00
        group by string_groupby
    ) as ca_00
    where ca_00.string_groupby = #temp_00.string_groupby and 
      ca_01.string_groupby = #temp_00.string_groupby and 
      ca_01.int_booking_year = #temp_00.int_booking_year
) as z
where z.row_num = 1
```

**Temp table columns:**

```
string_customer_name -> 'customer name'
string_customer_tpi -> 'customer id'
string_customer_region -> 'customer region'
string_industry_group -> 'customer industry group'
string_city -> 'customer city'
string_state -> 'customer state'
string_country -> 'customer country'
string_booking_type -> 'order type'
string_sales_branch -> 'sales branch'
string_sales_region -> 'sales region'
string_sales_area -> 'sales area of the world'
int_booking_year -> 'order year'
float_total -> 'order total in dollars'
string_groupby -> 'concatenation of customer name, customer city, customer state, 
  customer country, customer industry group'
```

**Execution Plan for posted query**

The XML for the query is too large to post.  Although the picture of the execution plan is small I the second post is where I think most of the time is at the Sort().  60% (posted query is 79% cost while the data pull is 21%) of both the initial data pull and the posted query is in the Sort().

[Query Execution Plan Link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyvZAiiM4)

[image]
[image]

Comment: you should post the XML for the actual execution plan

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm will get it posted shortly.

Comment: I have a hard time believing the the temp table approach is takes 5 times longer than the Cross Apply.   I've witnessed tremendous gains by re-tooling some queries to consume temp tables.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I did it multiple times.  It could the be architecture of my company or a server resource issue.  I promise it's the truth.

Comment: @Brent Fair enough... I promise I wan't calling you a liar.  :)

Comment: You can post the plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ . The actual plan XML contains a lot of useful info missing from your question

Comment: @MartinSmith posted; see the link in the execution plan section

Comment: The semantics of the query seem strange. It gets reduced down to 48,881 rows from 1,000,000 rows by just selecting any arbitrary row belonging to the year with the *lowest* `float_sum_total` for that `string_groupby` - are the values in the other selected columns guaranteed to be the same for all rows with the same `string_groupby, int_booking_year`?

Comment: @MartinSmith ```string_groupby``` is acting as key for summarization; for this application yes that is correct; i have to test this and potentially determine a better key; I'm actually trying to find the *highest* ```float_sum_total```

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure but the cross apply may be avoided if I understood what you were doing.
and that will help with the performance but as I dont have access to the data you must test it and see.

so I will start after you put the data in the temp table. try the below:-

```
 ;with TempWithSum as (
 --get the sum partition by string_groupby, int_booking_year
  select *,sum(float_total) over(partition by string_groupby, int_booking_year) as float_sum_total
  from @temp_00
 ),NamesCat as(
  --get all customer names grouped by string_groupby
  select string_groupby, STRING_AGG(cast(string_customer_tpi as varchar(max)), '|') as string_tpis_concat
  from @temp_00
  group by string_groupby
 ),AllData as(
 --get the row number partition string_groupby and ordered by string_groupby, float_sum_total
  select string_customer_name, string_customer_region, string_industry_group, string_city, z.string_state,
         string_country, string_booking_type, string_sales_branch, string_sales_region, string_sales_area,
         int_booking_year, float_sum_total, string_tpis_concat, string_groupby
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by string_groupby order by string_groupby, float_sum_total) as row_num
    from TempWithSum z
    inner join NamesCat on NamesCat.string_groupby=TempWithSum.string_groupby
  )
  select * from AllData where row_num=1
```

Hope it works and provide the result you need in the time frame you expect.

Note: I know you wanted to eliminate the row number, and im suggesting eliminating the cross apply, but your goal is the performance.